# Windows File Association using NSIS Script

Tags: windows, registry, nsis, file-association

I am using NSIS to create installer for my application. I want to provide the feature in which user can double click and open a file of a particular file extension in my application. I have followed instructions provided in this link: http://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2006-10-08-registering_windows_file_types_with_nsis/.

But it doesn't create registry key for me. My guess is that probably the installer has to be run as an administrator. But I don't unnecessarily want to prompt the user for administrative privilege.

How can I then associate my custom file type and icon with my application?

PS: I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: You might want to give [this macro](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File_Association) a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write the keys into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. This should work without administrator privileges under Vista and later.